# UITableViewController is not being shown on Main.storyboard file

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uistoryboard, xcode8

I have set some `UITableViewController` on my `Main.storyboard` and all of them works well but I noticed that only one of them, when I have opened my project today, has converted invisible.

I did not change anything of my project since I closed it last time and then I could see that `UITableViewController` properly. Despite this, it works on the project well. I can also access to each of its elements from the tree structure.

Here you can see what I mean:

[image]

I cannot reproduce it in others `UITableViewController` and I am using `Xcode8`.

Has someone faced it before? Have you solved it? Is it some kind of bug?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe its a bug in Xcode 8. Faced a same issue with tableView controller yesterday, only thing I had done is to change the device from iPhone to iPad Air and after everything disappeared from storyboard but when ran everything worked fine not even single auto layout crash :) So I believe it was an issue with Xcode 8. Here is what I did to overcome it, cleared derive data, closed Xcode before closing selected some swift file so when Xcode load again it won't load story board by default, now when I open story board its perfectly fine in all devices :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I have tried with that but it also does not work. It is still invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project: Product->clean

and maybe clean build folder: Product->press and hold alt->clean build folder.

EDIT:
Maybe try opening storyboard as source code, make a simple change to some element and undo the change. This helped me a lot with storyboard not reloading properly.

Comment: Yes, I already have cleaned with both options and the UITableViewController is still invisible.

Comment: Maybe try opening storyboard as source code, make a simple change to some element and undo the change.

Comment: It also does not work. It seems to be a bug of Xcode8.